# Delete all files and filegroup example

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Here is a simple filegroup,

```
USE master
GO
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2012
ADD FILEGROUP Test1FG1;
GO
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2012 
ADD FILE 
(
    NAME = test1dat3,
    FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\t1dat3.ndf',
    SIZE = 5MB,
    MAXSIZE = 100MB,
    FILEGROWTH = 5MB
),
(
    NAME = test1dat4,
    FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\t1dat4.ndf',
    SIZE = 5MB,
    MAXSIZE = 100MB,
    FILEGROWTH = 5MB
)
TO FILEGROUP Test1FG1;
GO
```

In this i want to delete all files assosiated with the group Test1FG1, and the group Test1FG1.
How to do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's simple to delete files and filegroups using [`ALTER DATABASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522469(v=sql.100).aspx); what exactly is your difficulty?

Comment: @Pondlife, thanks for response.. i need to specify the names manually to delete eg:test1dat4. i want to do it in some more optimized way i.e if i pass name of the filegroup all files assosiated with it should get deleted in oneshot. so any sample script is there for that?

Comment: You can query the data from [`sys.data_spaces`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190289(v=sql.100).aspx) and [`sys.master_files`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186782(v=sql.100).aspx) and use [dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) to build your script. Or if you prefer using .NET then you can use [SMO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms212724(v=sql.100).aspx) to manipulate files, filegroups and any other objects. This site generally isn't a "write my script" site, so it would be best if you try to do it yourself and ask for help if you're stuck.